# How to handle errors in the useEffect's skip in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I have this useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1)
  }, [someObject.someProperty.someNestedProperty])
```

Now lets say that `someProperty` is undefined.

It will force blank white screen - how to handle this in useEffect hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (someObject?.someProperty?.someNestedProperty) {
    console.log(1)
  }
}, [someObject])
```